# Automator Combine PDF Application

Tags: macos, automator, pdf

I have created almost an exact automator application as those who have posted before me and it goes as follows;

1) Get Selected Finder Items

2) Combine PDF pages

3) Move Finder Items (+show this action when the workflow runs)

yet when I drop in pdf files into the application icon I get double the pages I initially input. Is there anyone else running into this problem and is there a way around this?

And a related question concerning the naming of output file; what function do I need to add in order to custom name each pdf binder output? As I have read sequential naming doesn't work without a shell script, are there any other solutions which do not involve external scripts other than provided by the automator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *custom name* the combined **PDF** *files*, then add a **Rename Finder Items** *action* between the **Combine PDF Pages** *action* and the **Move Finder Items** *action*, with the **Options** set to checking the **Show this action when the workflow runs** *check box*. Set the **Rename Finder Items** *action* to **Name Single Item** and **Name: Basename only to: []**, where **[]** is and empty *text box*.

[image: Automator Workflow]

Note: When first added, the **Rename Finder Items** *action* shows as **Rename Finder Items** however, once you select **Name Single Item** in the first *pop-up list box* it changes the *name* of the *action* to **Name Single Item**.

The reason I suggest setting **Name: Basename only to: []** is the **.pdf** extension is added automatically when the document is saved, so there is no need to type it.

---

That said, I was able to reproduce the issue of double pages when using the above *workflow* as an *application* See mu Update: note below for the explanation. Another way to do it, without running as a *workflow* from within **Automator**, is to create it as an **Automator Service** *workflow* as show below:

This is then available in **Finder** from the **Finder** > **Services** *menu* or the **Services** *context menu* when selecting **PDF** *files* and *right-click* or *control-click* the selected files.

[image: Automator Service Workflow]

**Update:** The cause of the double pages when used as an *application* with your original *actions* is because of **Application receives files and folders as input**, which already receives the selected files and by adding a
**Get Selected Finder Items** *action* it is passing the selected files again and hence double the number of pages. If you want to use it as an application just remove the **Get Selected Finder Items** *action* from your original *workflow*.

Comment: well thanks, this takes care all of my problems and I don't have a preference over being an application or a service, matter of fact a service is more attractive. Yet this duplication of pages in an application is an automator problem/bug right?

Comment: @sle7en, It is not a bug. See the Update:, at the end of my answer.